# EXCEL: Find instance among many by looking at adjacent column

Tags: excel, compare, extract, formula

I have a rather large excel sheet 20k+ rows. My excel document has three sheets named CM, PP, and CH.

**CM** only contains the Information I use.

**PP** is the public Information that contains ALL data.

**CH** is my change log.

What I'm trying to do is take the values from my CM sheet in Column A *"CM(A)"* and find them in the PP sheet Column A *"PP(A)"*, then copy the found values from PP(A) and PP(F) "The sixth column over" to the third sheet CH(A) and CH(B).

This in of itself is rather simple, where I'm having a hard time is that sheet PP can contain multiple instances of the value in CM(A). The catch though is that I only need One of those specific values which is indicated by a value of "26" in column PP(B).

I just have no idea how to write the nested formula to make this happen.

[Visual Goal of Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xntL2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're unfamiliar with [Array Formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), you should definitely look into those as they are extremely helpful for tasks like this. You would need to use a conditional to test if the item occured more than once and then execute an `INDEX-MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` based on the results returned. I recreated your data structure and was able to achieve appropriate results using this formula in `B1` of sheet `CM`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(PP!A:A,A1)>1,INDEX(PP!F:F,MATCH(1,(PP!A:A=A1)*(PP!B:B=26),0)),VLOOKUP(A1,PP!A:F,6,FALSE))
```

Array formulas must be entered using Ctl+Shift+Enter, as is noted in the linked documentation.

Comment: Did not know about Array formulas definitely can spend some time on that alone. I tested out your formula in my exact same testing environment and I get the #N/A in the cell after pasting your formula into cell B1 and pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter. I'm not sure if I'm doing something else incorrectly? If I select a range past in the formula and press the Ctrl... I get all 0's in every field.

Comment: If you've entered it correctly, the formula should show that it's encased with brackets `{}` in the formula bar when you've got the cell selected. If it's not encased in brackets try double-clicking in the cell (or single click the formula bar) and repeat the Ctl+Shift+Enter process.

Comment: Yes I do have the {} in the formula bar, the result displayed in B1 on CH sheet is #N/A.

Comment: Okay, I've written mine in `B1` of sheet `CM`, per the screenshot provided. What is in `A1` of sheet `CH`?

Comment: Scratch that, I misread your original post. I thought I needed to put the formula in the CH sheet, you stated to place it in the CM sheet which overwrites the old data with the new data. It does work exactly as stated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, happy to have helped!

Comment: If I need to start this on row 5 instead of row 1 would I change all instances of "A1" to "A5"?

Comment: That's correct. Alternatively, you could just copy it down and then clear the first 4 rows.